# string substitution using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have this string in python

```
a = "haha" 
result = "hh"
```

What i would like to achieve is using regex to replace all occurrences of "aha" to "h" and all  "oho" to "h" and all "ehe" to "h"

"h" is just an example. Basically, i would like to retain the centre character. In other words, if its 'eae' i would like it to be changed to 'a'

My regex would be this

```
"aha|oho|ehe"
```

I thought of doing this

```
import re
reg = re.compile('aha|oho|ehe')
```

However, i am stuck on how to achieve this kind of substitution without using loops to iterate through all the possible combinations?

Comment: Use the reg.sub() method

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

print re.sub('aha|oho|ehe', 'h', 'haha')  # hh
print re.sub('aha|oho|ehe', 'h', 'hoho')  # hh
print re.sub('aha|oho|ehe', 'h', 'hehe')  # hh
print re.sub('aha|oho|ehe', 'h', 'hehehahoho')  # hhhahh
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `re.sub(r'[aeo]h[aeo]','h',a)` ?

Comment: This would also replace strings like "aho" and "eha".

Comment: This could replace other patterns such as `aho`. In that case, you would want to use a backreference i.e `re.sub(r'([aeo])h\1', 'h', s)`

Comment: I updated my question to replace it with an arbitary character instead